# How to store data to datastore - AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to Python & AppEngine.

I am trying to use Feedparser to cache a feed to a datastore.

My code is at http://pastebin.com/uWPdWUm2

For some reason it doesn't work - it does not add the data to the datastore.

Any ideas?  I am stumped.

Comment: post the code here and discuss here.

Answer (score 5):

You just forgot to use parenthesis in your model declaration.

Your code:

```
class FeedEntry3(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty
    link = db.StringProperty
    content = db.TextProperty
```

What it should be:

```
class FeedEntry3(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    link = db.StringProperty()
    content = db.TextProperty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting the values correcty or at all from feed parser? Have you tried to log them. Also for purpose of discussion if you think `x.put` is not working then separate that out and test that only e.g.

```
x = FeedEntry3()
x.title = "test title"
x.link = "test link"
x.content = "test content"
x.put()
```

Have you tried that, does that work? if that works most probably you are not getting values from feedparser, debug and log that.